# script to edit /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow

Tags: editing

let say i have 50 user where I need to delete in /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow

1. how to implement the script where it run under one script to edit and remove ID in /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow
2. how to get output in  every 10 line  the ID will appear like this

egrep '1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10' /etc/passwd
egrep '11|12|13|14|15...|20' /etc/passwd
egrep '|21..............|30' /etc/passwd

thanks in advance